# Create a HTML table from object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array and I want to create below HTML table from the array

[image]

I've tried writing the code bleow but seems like its appending rows in different places
Is there any other way to archive above table. im basically trying to create like Gannt chart kind of table

```js
// Extract unique years and months
var years = [...new Set(dataArray.map(item => item.StartYear))];
var months = [...new Set(dataArray.map(item => item.StartMonth).concat(dataArray.map(item =>
  item.EndMonth)))];

// Sort years and months
years.sort();
months.sort();

// Create the table dynamically
var tableHTML = '<table>';
tableHTML += '<tr><th>Year</th>';
years.forEach(year => tableHTML += `<th colspan="${months.length}">${year}</th>`);
tableHTML += '</tr>';
tableHTML += '<tr><td>Month</td>';
months.forEach(month => tableHTML += `<td>${month}</td>`);
tableHTML += '</tr>';

dataArray.forEach(item => {
  tableHTML += `<tr><td>${item.Project}</td>`;
  years.forEach(year => {
    months.forEach(month => {
      var isInProjectRange = (year === item.StartYear && month >= item.StartMonth && month <=
          item.EndMonth) ||
        (year === item.EndYear && month <= item.EndMonth);
      tableHTML += `<td>${isInProjectRange ? 'YES' : ''}</td>`;
    });
  });
  tableHTML += '</tr>';
});

tableHTML += '</table>';

// Append the table to the div with id 'table-container'
document.getElementById('table-container').innerHTML = tableHTML;
```

```html
<div id="table-container"></div>

<script>
var dataArray = [
    {'Project': 'Project 1', 'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 1.1', 'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 2', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 2.1', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 2.2', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Feb', 'EndMonth': 'Mar', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 2.3', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Mar', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom'}
     ];

</script>
```

Comment: I would start with `var tableHTML = '<table><thead>';..... tableHTML += '</tr></thead><tbody>';` but you are likely better off using an array for the HTML and join('') at the end

Comment: Note that sorting an array of month abbreviation strings will sort them alphabetically, not chronologically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet that demonstrates one possible way of doing it:

```js
// Extract unique years and months
const months = "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec".split(","),
      midx   = months.reduce((a,m,i)=>(a[m]=i,a),{}),
      proj    = dataArray.map(p=>[p.Project,100*p.StartYear+midx[p.StartMonth],100*p.EndYear+midx[p.EndMonth]]),
      d0=Math.min(...proj.map(([,p])=>p)), d1= Math.max(...proj.map(([,,p])=>p)),
      res = [["Year","Start","End","Owner"],["Month","","",""]].concat(dataArray.map(p=>[p.Project,p.StartMonth+"-"+p.StartYear,p.EndMonth+"-"+p.EndYear,p.Owner]));

for (let y=Math.floor(d0/100), m=d0 % 100; (d=100*y+m)<=d1; ++m) {
 if (m==12) {m=0;y++;d=100*y+m}
 res[0].push(y);res[1].push(months[m]); // table header row
 proj.forEach(([nam,a,b],i)=>res[i+2].push( d>=a && d<=b ? "YES" :"")) // table body rows
}
// Append the table to the div with id 'table-container'

const rep = res.shift().reduce((a,c,i)=>
  a.set(c,(a.get(c)||0)+1) // get the counts of each value c
,new Map());

document.getElementById('table-container').innerHTML = 
 "<thead><tr>"+[...rep.entries()].map(([t,n])=>`<th${n-1?` colspan="${n}"`:""}>${t}</th>`).join("")+"</tr></thead><tbody>"
 +res.map(r=>"<tr><td>"+r.join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>").join("\n")+"</tbody>";
```

```css
table {border-collapse:collapse}
td,th {border: 1px solid grey; padding:4px}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #eee}
```

```html
<table id="table-container"></table>

<script>
var dataArray = [
    {'Project': 'Project 1', 'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 1.1', 'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 2', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 2.1', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 2.2', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Feb', 'EndMonth': 'Mar', 'Owner':'Tom'},
    {'Project': 'Project 2.3', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Mar', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom'}
     ];

</script>
```

In order to have an easier structure to scan through I converted your `dataArray` into an array of arrays: `proj`. The subarrays of `proj` each contain three elements: the project name, a start date and an end date in numerical form (years*100 + month-index).

In order to make the months sortable I also translated them back into numerical forms and I keep the array `months` and `midx` for lookup purposes in both directions. `d0` and `d1` are the start and the end of the project tables overview (moin and max dates to be displayed).

In the main `for` loop I go from `d0` to `d1` and calculate the current year and month for each of the numerical dates. Whenever a new year is started I need to recalculate `m`,`y` and `d` (see after `if (m==12)`)

The rest of the loop is now concerned with storing a `YES` or a blank into the appropriate field of the 2D array `res`.

**Update**

I added the `colspan` mechanism for the table header. This involves the use of a `Map` object. Now the result should look exactly like the expected one.

I am sure my answer can be simplified further. Go ahead and try it  ...

Comment: expected outcome is different from your answer. there should be an less completed way to solve this

Comment: I guess, there are less complicated ways of solving your problem. Go ahead and find them ;-) ! However, I added a few bits to my solution to make the result look like OP specified it.

Comment: yes even though bit completed to i can accept this thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tried doing it my way and it's a bit longer than the accepted answer but I think a nicer solution in my opinion.

Since your example table, never had a project that lasted more than one year or at least sometime in both years I've considered it might happen.

The first object of **dataArray** is changed so it lasts three years so you can see the effect if the project lasts longer.

### Quick explanation:

- I sorted months using an object of them with assigned number as values.
- Extracted all years and all months available for those years into ***yearsAndMonthSpan*** variable
- Created ***formattedDataArray*** variable where the original object was formatted with a new property with its own ***yearAndMonths*** in which the project is worked in
- ***withHtml*** variable is getting the project objects ready for making HTML code
- Created HTML variables and included them in the ***table*** variable for better readability

  - headersHtml
  - subheadersHtml
  - projectsHtml

Hope it helps

### Check the snippet:

```js
const dataArray = [{
    Project: 'Project 1',
    StartYear: '2022',
    EndYear: '2024',
    StartMonth: 'Nov',
    EndMonth: 'Mar',
    Owner: 'Tom'
  },
  {
    Project: 'Project 1.1',
    StartYear: '2022',
    EndYear: '2022',
    StartMonth: 'Mar',
    EndMonth: 'May',
    Owner: 'Tom'
  },
  {
    Project: 'Project 2',
    StartYear: '2024',
    EndYear: '2024',
    StartMonth: 'Jan',
    EndMonth: 'May',
    Owner: 'Tom'
  },
  {
    Project: 'Project 2.1',
    StartYear: '2024',
    EndYear: '2024',
    StartMonth: 'Jan',
    EndMonth: 'Feb',
    Owner: 'Tom'
  },
  {
    Project: 'Project 2.2',
    StartYear: '2024',
    EndYear: '2024',
    StartMonth: 'Feb',
    EndMonth: 'Mar',
    Owner: 'Tom'
  },
  {
    Project: 'Project 2.3',
    StartYear: '2024',
    EndYear: '2024',
    StartMonth: 'Mar',
    EndMonth: 'May',
    Owner: 'Tom'
  },
]
const monthOrder = {
  Jan: 0,
  Feb: 1,
  Mar: 2,
  Apr: 3,
  May: 4,
  Jun: 5,
  Jul: 6,
  Aug: 7,
  Sep: 8,
  Oct: 9,
  Nov: 10,
  Dec: 11,
}

// Extract unique years and months
const years = [...new Set(dataArray.map((item) => [item.StartYear, item.EndYear]).flat())].sort()
// Sort years
years.sort()

// All years with all months from all projects.
let yearsAndMonthSpan = {}

// Loop through years of project and get months for each year.
// Added maxMonthSpan property just for the sake of it
const formattedDataArray = dataArray.map((item) => {
  const {
    StartYear,
    EndYear,
    StartMonth,
    EndMonth
  } = item

  const months = Object.keys(monthOrder)
  const startYear = Number(StartYear)
  const endYear = Number(EndYear)

  let loopYear = startYear
  let startMonthIndex = monthOrder[StartMonth]
  let yearAndMonths = {}

  while (loopYear <= endYear) {
    const endLoopNumber = loopYear === endYear ? monthOrder[EndMonth] + 1 : months.length
    let tempMonths = []

    for (let i = startMonthIndex; i < endLoopNumber; i++) {
      tempMonths = [...tempMonths, months[i]]
    }

    yearAndMonths[loopYear] = tempMonths

    if (!yearsAndMonthSpan[loopYear]) yearsAndMonthSpan[loopYear] = [tempMonths]
    yearsAndMonthSpan[loopYear] = [...new Set([...yearsAndMonthSpan[loopYear], tempMonths].flat())].sort((a, b) => {
      return monthOrder[a] - monthOrder[b]
    })

    loopYear++
    startMonthIndex = 0
  }

  return {
    ...item,
    years: yearAndMonths,
    maxMonthSpan: Object.values(yearAndMonths).flat().filter(Boolean).length,
  }
})

// Added HTML for each month with either YES or empty string
// Formatted the returned project object for usage in making HTML table code easier
const withHtml = formattedDataArray.map((item) => {
  let markedMonths = []

  for (const year in yearsAndMonthSpan) {
    markedMonths = [
      ...markedMonths,
      yearsAndMonthSpan[year].map((month, iMap) => {
        if (!item.years[year]) return '<td></td>'
        return item.years[year].includes(month) ? '<td>YES</td>' : '<td></td>'
      }),
    ]
  }

  return {
    owner: item.Owner,
    start: `${item.StartMonth}-${item.StartYear}`,
    end: `${item.EndMonth}-${item.EndYear}`,
    projectName: item.Project,
    getHtml: markedMonths,
  }
})

const headersStaticTitles = ['Year', 'Start', 'End', 'Owner']
const yearHeaders = Object.entries(yearsAndMonthSpan)
const monthHeaders = Object.values(yearsAndMonthSpan).flat()

// Headers HTML
const headersHtml = `<tr>
      ${headersStaticTitles.map((title) => `<th>${title}</th>`)}
      ${yearHeaders.map((item) => `<th colspan="${item[1].length}">${item[0]}</th>`)}
    </tr>`

// Subheaders HTML
const subheadersHtml = `<tr>
      <td>Month</td>
      ${Array(3)
        .fill()
        .map((x) => `<td></td>`)}
      ${monthHeaders.map((item) => `<th>${item}</th>`)}
    </tr>`

// Projects HTML
const projectsHtml = withHtml.map((item) => {
  return `<tr>
        <td>${item.projectName}</td>
        <td>${item.start}</td>
        <td>${item.end}</td>
        <td>${item.owner}</td>
        ${item.getHtml}
      </tr>`
})

// Removed commas from arrays since it showed them above the table.
const arrayToString = (arr) => arr.toString().replaceAll(',', '\n')

// Improved table
const table = `
        <table>
          ${arrayToString(headersHtml)}

          ${arrayToString(subheadersHtml)}

          ${arrayToString(projectsHtml)}
        </table>
      `
document.getElementById('table-container').innerHTML = table
```

```css
table {border-collapse:collapse}
td,th {border: 1px solid grey; padding:4px}
th {min-width: 100px;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #eee}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="table-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```